# git clone via ssh from gitlab leads to "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: ssh, gitlab

If created a new ssh-key, copied and pasted the public-key to the gitlab project and created a conifg-file in ~/.ssh ...

Still I can't clone the project (I'm not the owner, but I was added as user)

That's what I try (of course I'm using the correct path):

```
git clone -v git@gitlab.foo.bar.com:bla/blub.git
```

this gives me

```
cloning to 'blub' ...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: couldn't read from Remote-Repository
```

Then I tried the following

```
ssh -vT -i ~/.ssh/gitlab git@gitlab.foo.bar.com:bla
```

which gives me

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2j-fips  26 Sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /user/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [52.167.219.168] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /user/me/.ssh/gitlab type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /user/me/.ssh/gitlab-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /user/me/.ssh/gitlab type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /user/me/.ssh/gitlab-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw
debug1: Host 'gitlab.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /user/me/.ssh/known_hosts:26
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /user/me/.ssh/gitlab
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /user/me/.ssh/gitlab
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I really don't get it...Cloning and pulling via http works pefectly fine.
SSH doesn't.

Any hints?

EDIT: the config-file in ~/.ssh looks like this (as suggested [here](https://gitlabext.iag.uni-stuttgart.de/help/ssh/README#locating-an-existing-ssh-key-pair))

```
Host gitlab.foo.bar.com
RSAAuthentication yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab
```

the private key is named gitlab and the public one is gitlab.pub

EDIT2:
Permission for ~/.ssh is set to 700
and for ~/.ssh/* set to 600

Comment: What did you changed in ssh config? Can be key permissions too.

Comment: Your ssh client offered /user/me/.ssh/gitlab to the server, and the server didn't accept it. It's not a valid key for the server, or your gitlab account is disabled, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. This has worked for me.

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add
```